# How to change date format in angular 8

Tags: javascript, angular

I am using datepicker for date column and it is date datatype but after submit this  input type date format not correct so i want to change date format

I am using bsConfig bootstrap in angular 8.
but i dont know how to  change this format

bankend passing a array for input type code:-

```
  'ede_date_of_joining' => array(
                    'type' => 'date',
                    'description' => 'Employment Start Date',
                    'visible' => true,
                    'required' => true,
                    'size' => 50,
                    'date_format' => 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS',
                    'table_name' => 'employment_details',
                    'column_name' => 'ede_date_of_joining',
                    'data_column_name' => 'ede_date_of_joining'
                ),
```

frontend angular 8 code  template

```
  <div [formGroup]="form" >
        <ng-container *ngIf="field.read_only; else textBoxElseBlock">
          <ng-container *ngIf="field.read_only === 'N'">
            <input type="text" class="form-control edit-mode-field"
              bsDatepicker
              [minDate]="minDate"
              [maxDate]="maxDate"
              [formControlName]="field.code" />
            <span class="view-mode-field">{{ field.value }}</span>
          </ng-container>
          <ng-container *ngIf="field.read_only === 'Y'">
              <span class="">{{ field.value }}</span>
          </ng-container>
        </ng-container>
        <ng-template #textBoxElseBlock>
          <input type="text" class="form-control edit-mode-field"
            bsDatepicker
            [minDate]="minDate"
            [maxDate]="maxDate"
            [formControlName]="field.code"
            [bsConfig]="datePickerConfig"/>
          <span class="view-mode-field">{{ field.value }}</span>
        </ng-template>
      </div>
```

Comment: What kind of DatePicker are you using ? Can you provide a demo?

Answer (score 1):

You are using some kind of php datepicker, not compatible with Angular 8. If you manage to find a datepicker for angular, you can always format the date with angular date pipe

> https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe

Answer (score 0):

https://momentjs.com you can update you're prop(date_format)'s value with this JavaScript library..